# Match first next word matching a given pattern using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm having trouble getting the following behaviour:

```
input='somestring... --key1 val1 --key2 val2 --key3 val3 somestring...'
output='val1'
```

I tried using:

```
echo $input | sed -nE 's/.*--key1 (.*) (--.*)$/\1/p' 
#but this gives 'val1 --key2 val2' instead of 'val1'
```

Basically, my issue is that I do not know how to tell `sed` to match the pattern in reverse order (so that `--key2` is not captured in `\1`). I believe there is a simple way here but I cannot find it?

edit: a fix could be to use:

```
echo $input | sed -nE 's/.*--key1 ([^(--)]*) (--.*)$/\1/p'
```

But I would like to know if a "better" solution exists for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `(.*)` is too greedy.

perl has non-greedy matching:

```
perl -nE 'if (/--key1 (.*?) --/) {say $1}' <<< "$input"
```

If you actually want to use proper option parsing:

```bsh
eval set -- "$(getopt --long key1:,key2:,key3: -- $input)"   # $input is unquoted!

while :; do
    case "$1" in
        --key1) key1=$2; shift 2;;
        --key2) key2=$2; shift 2;;
        --key3) key3=$2; shift 2;;
        --) shift; break;;
    esac
done

[[ "$output" = "$key1" ]] && echo OK
```

Comment: So `sed` has no equivalent to (.*?) non-greedy matching... ahh, too bad! I could use getopt version but I tend to think it too much verbose, so I'll keep my sed ugly solution for yet!

Comment: If you know the argument has no whitespace, you could write: `sed 's/.*--key1 ([^[:blank:]]\+).*/\1/'` but that's a big assumption IMO.

Comment: Indeed, argument can contain actually everything (even `--`) :/...